# Unity detecting edge of mesh or end of mesh

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, procedural-generation, mesh

I'm trying to create procedurally generated tiles and I've reached a point where I need to figure out the boundaries of the mesh or the outer vertices of the mesh.

[image]

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(bound[ i ].v2, Vector3.forward, out hit)) {
    if (hit.distance > 2) {
```

I've tried raycasting all the vertices, but still can't get the vertices of the edge. The mesh does have a collider. any help on how i would go about this is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this post about getting the outer/edge vertices from a Mesh? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1019436/get-outeredge-vertices-c.html

Comment: Link-only answers are generally discouraged. Adding a basic summary of the key points recommended at the link would make this answer both clearer and more future-proof in case of link rot. ;)

Comment: i did check that out, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your mesh will always be a rectangle you could use the MeshCollider, or more specifically `MeshCollider.bounds.extents` but that will only return 1/2 the width, length and height, not the vertices.

Depending on what you need to accomplish or the environment you are creating, this may work. If not, let us know what you plan on doing with the data after you get it and that may help clear things up.